# Android Mail Api with pdf file attachment possibility?

Tags: android, email, pdf, attachment

I'm new to Android development. I'm trying to write an an app that will allow the submission of a pdf file **chosen by the user**. is there any API that allows this or do I have to write a file explorer, get the path and use gmail tp send the email with the pdf attachment !?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To let the user pick a PDF file, use [an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Storage), for a MIME type of `application/pdf`.

To allow the user to send the email, [use `ACTION_SEND`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email) (if the user is picking the recipient) or `ACTION_SENDTO` (if you already know the address of the recipient). Use `EXTRA_STREAM` to pass in the `Uri` you got from the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` request.